# $('.button').on("DOMSubtreeModified") does not work in chrome/safari, but works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

What is the reason that below code does not work in Chrome/Safari but works great in FireFox?

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
        alert("button value changed");
    });
});
```

Is there any alternate way to make it happen in other browsers? I'm trying to detect the button value change.

What event to bind with .button for button value change dynamically?

Comment: I think Mouser and user625488 have misread the question. They're telling you how to get the functionality of `DOMSubtreeModified` events, not `change` events.

Comment: The code sample in the question specifically uses `DOMSubtreeModified`. You can also specifically observe the change of the `value` attribute using mutation observers. I don't see how the two answers referring to mutation observers miss the point.

Answer (score 5):

In my perception onchange only fires on input elements when the input is changed. Since you're referring to button the input is not changing and a `change` event will not fire. So you'll need a solution that monitors the changes to an element:

For modern browsers I would recommend *mutation observers*:

```
        var observer = new MutationObserver( [observer function] );
        // configuration of the observer:
        var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true };

        // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
        observer.observe(element, config);
```

This adds a mutation observer to your element. You can configure the options to which the observer needs to listen. *Jquery* doesn't support this natively (yet).

> - **childList** Set to true if additions and removals of the target node's child elements (including text nodes) are to be observed.
>     attributes Set to true if mutations to target's attributes are to be observed.
> - **characterData** Set to true if mutations to target's data are to be observed.
> - **subtree** Set to true if mutations to not just target, but also target's descendants are to be observed.
> - **attributeOldValue** Set to true if attributes is set to true and target's attribute value before the mutation needs to be recorded.
> - **characterDataOldValue** Set to true if characterData is set to true and target's data before the mutation needs to be recorded.
> - **attributeFilter** Set to an array of attribute local names (without namespace) if not all attribute mutations need to be observed.
>
> *Source: MDN*

Which browsers supports this: [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver)

Read more here: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

For your project:

```
$(".button").each(function(){
    this.observer = new MutationObserver( observeButtonChange);
    // configuration of the observer:
    //you can play with these.
    var config = { attributes: false, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: false};

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    this.observer.observe(this, config); //starts the actual observing of the element.

});

function observeButtonChange(mutations)
{
    alert("Button has changed");
}
```

This code searches all the elements on the page with class name `.button` and uses jQuery's `each` to attach a *Mutation Observer* to it. Every time the *DOM tree* of the `button` is changed it will trigger the `observeButtonChange` function. The event object `mutations` contains a lot of information about the triggered event including the elements that were added and deleted. It's an array containing data about the various listeners. I would recommend to listen to the `characterData` and `childList` option since they indicate a change in the value of the button.

Comment: Downvoting without commenting, great.

Comment: Great answer, my DOMSubtreeModified was in a loop (only in IE and Firefox) because I was editing the dom after it was modified - dynamically adding content, and when it updated, tidy it up with javascript. This has solved my problem at least

Answer (score 0):

## NEW ANSWER

2nd try! What I would do is use a combination of jQuery ON and TRIGGER.

Create a custom event listener like below:

```
$( ".button" ).on( "dynValueChange", function() {
    alert("button value changed");
});
```

Then, add the below trigger to the function that dynamically changes the button value.

```
$(".button").trigger("dynValueChange");
```

This may not be as clean or easy as using DOMSubtreeModified, but I can guarantee it will work for all browsers.

Let me know if this needs a better explanation.

## ORIGINAL ANSWER

Try using the code below. This utilizes jQueries change function to apply an event handler on the ".button" element. This only works if the value attribute on the element ".button" changes.

```
$(function() {
    $('.button').change(function(){
        alert("button value changed");
    });
});
```

Good Luck!
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Adam

Comment: it doesn't work. My button value changes dynamically.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't factor in the DOM modification. I have a solution, but it does not apply a DOM Modification Event Listener.

Answer (score 0):

[The section about legacy events in the DOM level 3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#legacy-mutationevent-events) should give you an answer why this event isn't implemented in all browsers, why it works inconsistently, why it will be available in less browsers as time passes, and why it's generally a bad idea to use it. TL;DR; it's slow, therefore it was deprecated, and support for it is being removed as newer browser versions are released.

At the same time, [the section about mutation observers in the newest DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers) provides a replacement.

The Mozilla Developer Network provides a less dry, [more hands-on usable description of mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). jQuery doesn't provide built-in shortcuts for using mutation observers, so you'll have to attach your observer to the DOM manually - but you can use jQuery for all the rest.

A mutation observer can be attached like so:

```
var target = $(".button" )[0];
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // body of your handler comes here - you can use jQuery in here
    // typically, you iterate over mutations here, and handle
    // each according to its type
});
// additional members for configuration documented in the spec
// attributes: true says the observer should receive a mutation
// when an attribute of the watched target changes
var observerConfig = { attributes: true }; 
observer.observe(target, observerConfig);
```

Later on, when you are done observing mutations, you should destroy your mutation observer, to make garbage collection easy for the browser:

```
observer.disconnect();
```

The `mutations` argument received by the function you pass to the mutation observer is an array of `MutationRecord` - also described in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutationrecord). This interface has various members for querying its type (attribute change, text change, children added or removed etc.), and what the changes were - name of the changed  attribute and its value before change, for a mutation of type `attributes`.

Mind you, the above code sample only attaches to the first element with class `button` in your DOM. You'd need to call `observer.observe()` for each target, to attach it to all elements with class `button`:

```
$('.button').each(function(index, element) {
    observer.observe(element, config);
});
```

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#queuing-a-mutation-record) you can use one observer to observe mutations on several elements, so you don't need to create a new one for each `.button`.

I don't think that will be as convenient as the DOM  mutation events. But what you want is still doable.

Comment: Separate Mutation Observers allow disconnecting for the specific element only. In your code calling disconnect will stop the listening for all attached elements.

Comment: @Mouser You're absolutely right. But that's what the code sample in the question tries to accomplish too - attach the same handler to all `.button` elements. In de facto standard jQuery idiom, you'd later on call `$(".button").off("dynValueChange")` to remove the event handler.